# Instantiate ViewModel property as element in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ViewModel with `MyGeometry` property of type `Geometry`.

In XAML View, I have a `GeometryGroup`.

I would like the following:

```
<GeometryGroup>
    <EllipseGeometry ... />
    <RectangleGeometry ... />
    <!-- How can I put `MyGeometry` here?
     I'm pretty sure I've seen something similar before -->
</GeometryGroup>
```

So, the broad question is: How can I instantiate some viewmodel property directly in XAML as a "standalone" element, instead of binding it to some other element's property? (if at all possible, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really nice, but works:

```
<GeometryGroup>
    <EllipseGeometry ... />
    <RectangleGeometry ... />
    <CombinedGeometry Geometry1="{Binding MyGeometry}"/>
</GeometryGroup>
```

Comment: That was smart. For the record - since it is the solution principle here) it seems that the only built-in Geometry subtype having a dependency property of type Geometry is CombinedGeometry. If that was not the case, it would be possible to create some subclass from Geometry, and add a dependency property of type Geometry to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach is:

```
<GeometryGroup>
    <EllipseGeometry ... />
    <RectangleGeometry ... />
    <MyGeometry Prop1="{Binding Prop1_InViewModel}" Prop2="{Binding Prop2_InViewModel}" ... />
</GeometryGroup>
```

Where `Prop1_InViewModel` and `Prop2_InViewModel` are properties of your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Actually I don't have a type `MyGeometry`. It is a `Geometry` property of my ViewModel. I want to add it as an element of `GeometryGroup`.

Comment: Does it mean that you doesn't know the type of your Geometry at compile-time? If so, you cant create the templates for all possible types and select the template at run-time by `TemplateSelector`.

Comment: `MyGeometry` is of type `StreamGeometry`. It is a ViewModel property. I want my XAML-difined `GeometryGroup` to contain it as one of its children (other children are there only to give the general idea).

Comment: If you have `StreamGeometry` you can bind it to `Path.Data`. But it is not good idea to construct View element in ViewModel.